# Parsing and processing JSON response with NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, rest, json.net, json-deserialization

I am using Rest services for my service integration.

I am using asp.net and my data comes from EAN Api. The rest response return 200 hotels and that hotels all info such as all rooms, images, prices, details, fees.....

I want to parse and deserialize that complex response (there are complex rest json response:http://developer.ean.com/docs/hotel-list/examples/rest-data-options/)

So I used [online json to csharp generator](http://json2csharp.com) but that generator generates wrong data.

For example, instead of providing `list< Rooms >` it generates `object Rooms`.

When I modify the classes it gives an error for the following line

```
   Response.RootObject sonuc 
     = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response.RootObject>(responseFromServer);
```

Comment: According to my thought, Its not a fault in json2csharp. Check your json you used to generate c# classes. Check whethere there is a json array of Rooms. Under Rooms, if there is only one child, class generator won't know it is supposed to be a list. as an example  If it is like this `"HotelSummary" : {}`, the generator get it as a single object, but if you entered `"HotelSummary" : [{},{},{}]` it will interpret as a list. That may be the class generator problem as I see. What is the error you get at the above line?

Comment: @Deepal when i change it manuel it give below error : Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Tourism.Plugin.Expedia.Response.RoomRateDetailsList]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object

Comment: I think the issue is with the data sent from the server. It should send the data as an array with `[]` even if the number of elements is 1. As an example, have a look at following json responses. In the first response, although there's only one result, it comes as an element of a json array instead of a single object.

http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Spirit:+Stallion+of+the+Cimarron
http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=up

Comment: I have previously used json2csharp with the above omdb api as exactly as you did. But my results were perfect.

Comment: @Deepal yes problem is with server.we open ticket but no answear yet...when i convert object to arraylist it give error but when use object it still give same error

Comment: You mean Object class?